# jQuery filter by rel

Tags: jquery, filter, rel

I am trying to filter for all the links with a rel attribute, and then change that attribute. I know it should be simple ... but cannot get it working.

```
$('#selector a[rel]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('rel', 'lightbox[auto_group999]');
});
```

Comment: And here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/3W7P8/ - Did you run this on load or DOM ready?

Comment: Show you HTML which you can't get it working with.

Comment: http://weddings.garretthubbard.com/portfolio/weddings/

Comment: It is within a $(document).ready... but I suppose it's probably executing before the photos load?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){ // DOM is ready to be manipulated

    $('#selector a[rel]').each(function() { // now the selector is retrieved
      $(this).attr('rel', 'lightbox[auto_group999]');
    });

});
```

<kbd>**[jQuery API - .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**</kbd>